# Can I get a UICollectionViewCell by tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some NSNotifications going on and I want to update my cells based on the tags associated with them.

Is this possible?

To elaborate I have a UILabel and a UIProgressView in my UITableViewCell that I will want to update if the notification object contains a matching tag.

I am syncing data in the background and each time I process a chunk of data I send out a NSNotification.

I want the UICollectionView cells to reflect the most current status.

To make this happen I would like to grab the UITableViewCell by tag and then update the UILabel and UIProgressView with new data.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you have any code handy?

Comment: Using `tag` Is probably not advisable. It's probably more prudent to include some identifier that your model can use to identify the affected cell, and then have your observer translate that to an `NSIndexPath` and see if that cell is currently visible. But without more info regarding your model, it's going to be hard to advise you further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't get cells by tag, get them by `indexPath`
2. Don't get cells by `indexPath`
3. Don't get them

(1) You can get the views by tag but you'd need to update the views tag each time they are drawn to match their index paths.  So (2) the index paths are just as good.  But (3) they are no good either, because tweaking cells directly is not how we do it in MVC-land

The correct plan here is to update your model (in MVC terms, the collection view datasource array more specifically) to reflect a change in the world, then tell your collection view that it is out of date (`reloadData` is the big hammer, `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` is the scalpel).

This means that your model must contain data reflecting the state of download progress (like a float) that can be used as a progress bar parameter, and that your cellForItem... method must inspect this value and modify the cell's progress view.

Comment: He doesn't know which index paths to reload though.

Comment: @MrHaze - that's not clear from the OP.  The OP certainly can and should be able to map the download process to the corresponding datasource objects.  Thats a precondition for tags and indexPaths, too.

Comment: Sure, I don't disagree, however if all you have a is a reference to the cell tag, you can't fetch the index path only based on that.

Comment: Correct @MrHaze, I am just going to have my UICollectionView cells respond to the notifications and see how my performance is.  Just seems lame to have 10 cells checking a notification to see if it is a match when most likely it will not be.

Comment: @Slee - the common pattern is to attach an attribute to the NSNotification (see userInfo) that describes the model -- the part of your datasource -- that cares about the notification.  If the collection shows a bunch of downloads from a bunch of urls, then the notification user info would contain a specific url where the progress has changed.  Upon receiving the notification, the view controller's job is to find the index of the model object in the datasource, update it's progress (also part of the model), and reload at the corresponding indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because cells will reuse every time.If you wrap tags,this is not easier than just reloading cells.If you want to do this ,you should update your models and then reload updated cells.